# Given numbers a1,a2,...,an whose sum is positive. Find the minimal number s.t. the sum of numbers less than or equal to it is positive, in linear time

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

**Problem:** Given `n` different numbers `a1,a2,...,an`, whose sum is positive. Show how one can find the minimal number such that the sum of numbers less than or equal to it is positive, in time-complexity of `O(n)`.

**Note**: the numbers aren't necessarily whole and they aren't necessarily sorted as given.

**Some explanation of the problem:** if the array was sorted, `[x,x,x,y,x,...,x,x,x]` and y is the first number such that summing all the numbers up-to it will give a positive/zero sum ( and summing less numbers up-to it will give negative sum ), then `y` will be returned. ( the `x` here is just a place holder for a number, all numbers in the array are different )

**Attempt:**
Define the parameters  `low , high = 0, n` which will serve as boundaries for the summation of the elements within them and also as boundaries for choosing the pivot.
Chose a pivot randomly and partition the array ( for example, by Lomuto's partition ), denote this pivot's index as `p'`. The partitioning will cost `O(n)`. Sum the numbers from `low` to `p'` and designate the sum of these numbers as `s`.
If `s<0` define `low=p'`, and repeat the process of choosing a random pivot ( whose index will be denoted as `p'` ) and parititoning between `low` and `high` and then summing the numbers between these two bounderies as `s := s + the new summation value`.
Else, define `high=p'` and repeat the process described in the 'If' condition above.
The process will end when `low = high`.

---

Besides a few logical gaps in my attempt, it's overall complexity is `O(n)` on average and not at worst-case.
Do you have any ideas as to how solve the problem in `O(n)` time?, I thought maybe using a manipulation of 'Median of Medians' algorithm  but I have no idea.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a linear time solution exists?

Comment: Yes, it is a question from some homework few years back. It appears immediately after studying  'Median of Medians' algorithm, whose cost equation is `T(n) <= O(n) + T(n/5) + T(0.75n)` ( whose solution is `T(n) = O(n)` )

Comment: I think this is the solution: Find median using Median-of-Medians algorithm, this takes O(n). Partition the array according to the median, this takes O(n). Then, sum the numbers up to the median,if it is negative continue the same process on the right half of the partitioned array which will have `n/2` elements. otherwise, continue the process on the left half of the partition array which will have `n/2` elements. The complexity of this process is `T(n) = O(n) + T(n/2)` which gives `T(n) = O(n)`.  This algorithm needs a bit of mixing and tidying with my above attempt, but I think this is it.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 It is even easier than that. Just find pivots as in median of medians algorithm, and use sums as you suggested in your problem description.